# UIBarButtonItem not disabled until view changes

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have a UINavigationController and am using the toolbar in one of my view controllers. I have several UIBarButtonItems. At various points, I disable certain buttons in the toolbar, using things like `_btnEdit.enabled = NO`.

This all works well except for one time where this happens when there is no user interaction. In that case, the button appears to be enabled (isn't grayed out), but doesn't accept touches. If I cover the bar with something (an action sheet from the bottom) or change the orientation of the device, it shows correctly.

I've tried `self.navigationController.toolbar setNeedsDisplay]` and `[self.navigationController.toolbar drawRect:self.navigationController.toolbar.bounds]` but neither have an any effect.

Any ideas on how to "refresh" this view? I know UIBarButtonItems don't inherit from UIView, which I feel like may be contributing to the issue.

Comment: Check if _btnEdit is nil when you are setting that.

Comment: It's not nil. This is further shown by the button being disabled when the orientation is changed.

Comment: Can you please put some more code to explain as to how you are disabling the buttons and in which situation it is not working correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the intended behaviour. The setNeedsDisplay is a good reflex try, but you don't own the navigation bar and `UIBarButtonItem doesn't inherit from UIView`, so we need to think of them a little differently.
Here how you can achieve your goal :

```
UIBarButtonItem *bbi = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem;
bbi.enabled = NO;
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:bbi animated:YES];
```

NOTE : `self` is a `UIViewController`
I've just made a quick test with this and it's working.

Comment: This may work, but the buttons are in a toolbar, not the right bar button item. The way I got it to work is similar, though. After I changed the enabled state, I just called: `[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:NO];
                [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];`, which forced the toolbar to redraw.

Comment: @Ned UIToolBar Have you try `setItems:animated` in the same fashion ?